# change detection on @Input object in custom directive

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a an object

```
person: {name: string, age: number}
```

I have a custom directive with an @Input object

```
pPerson: any;
@Input()
set person(value: any) {
    this.pPerson = value;
    this.hasModelChanged = true;
}
```

In the parent component I have this function

```
nfAfterViewInit() {
 person.name = 'Jean'
 person.age = 20
}
```

My parent component html looks like this

```
<div customDirective [person]="person"></div>
```

The problem is that when person properties are modified in the component the changes are not detected in the custom directive. Since angular is not deep checking the @Input, what would be a proper way to force the change detection or to catch the changes in the custom directive?

I can't use ngDoCheck since it's called so many times.

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.person = { ...this.person, name: 'Jean', age: 20 }
}`

Comment: The reference itself has to change for change detection to see it, not just one of its properties.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I don't want to have to change the reference of the object every time I'm just modifying one of its properties, do you have another solution?

Comment: I would start by reading [this](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4).